# Unknown reason of dead multiprocessing in python-3.5

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.5

I have a data frame `df` contains information of two-hundred-thousand items. And now I want to measure their pair-wise similarity and pick up the top `n` pairs. That means, I should calculate nearly tens of billions calculation. Given the huge computation cost, I choose to run it via multiprocessing. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
user_list = (list(range(1, 200001))
def gen_pair():
    for u1 in reversed(user_list):
        for u2 in reversed(list(range(1, u1))):
            yield (u1, u2)

def cal_sim(u_pair):
    u1, u2 = u_pair
    # do sth quite complex...
    sim = sim_f(df[u1], df[u2])
    if sim < 0.5:
        return None
    else:
        return (u1, u2, sim)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    vals = pool.map(cal_sim, gen_pair())
    for v in vals:
        if v is not None:
            with open('result.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n'.format(v[0], v[1], v[2]))
```

When I just take the first 1000 users, it works quite well. But when I take all of them, it is kind of dead and no single word in `result.txt`. But if I add the number of processes, it also be dead. I wonder what is the reason and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is my code of `sim_f`:

```
def sim_f(t1, t2):
    def intersec_f(l1, l2):
        return set(l1)&set(l2)

    def union_f(l1, l2):
        return set(l1)|set(l2)

    a_arr1, a_arr2 = t1[0], t1[1]
    b_arr1, b_arr2 = t2[0], t2[1]
    sim =  float(len(union_f(intersec_f(a_arr1, a_arr2), intersec_f(b_arr1, b_arr2))))\
        / float(len(union_f(union_f(a_arr1, a_arr2), union_f(b_arr1, b_arr2))))
    return sim
```

Comment: Your description says " twenty-thousand", but your code `range(1, 2000001)` has 2 million items.  Which is it?  Because it's a quadratic-time approach, a factor-of-100 difference in input size is a factor-of-10000 difference in expected work.

Comment: @TimPeters Sorry, I have already fixed the mistake.

Comment: Now the code says `range(1, 200001)`, which is 200 thousand items, not 20 thousand.  You should also check your math.  If it really is 20000, then `choose(20000, 2)` is 199.990,000, much smaller than "nearly tens of billions".

Comment: @TimPeters Yes it is 200 thousand indeed. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's little to go on, but try:

```
vals = pool.imap(cal_sim, gen_pair())
            ^
```

instead:  note that I changed "map" to "imap".  As documented, `map()` blocks until the *entire* computation is complete, so you never get to your `for` loop until all the work is finished.  `imap` returns "at once".

And if you don't care in which order results are delivered, use `imap_unordered()` instead.

### OPENING THE FILE JUST ONCE

With respect to an issue raised in comments:

```
with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    for v in vals:
        if v is not None:
            f.write('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n'.format(v[0], v[1], v[2]))
```

is the obvious way to open the file just once.  But I'd be surprised if it helped you - all evidence to date suggests it's just that `cal_sim()` is plain expensive.

### SPEEDING SIM_F

There's lots of redundant work being done in:

```
def sim_f(t1, t2):
    def intersec_f(l1, l2):
        return set(l1)&set(l2)

    def union_f(l1, l2):
        return set(l1)|set(l2)

    a_arr1, a_arr2 = t1[0], t1[1]
    b_arr1, b_arr2 = t2[0], t2[1]
    sim =  float(len(union_f(intersec_f(a_arr1, a_arr2), intersec_f(b_arr1, b_arr2))))\
    / float(len(union_f(union_f(a_arr1, a_arr2), union_f(b_arr1, b_arr2))))
    return sim
```

Wholly untested, here's an obvious ;-) rewrite:

```
def sim_f(t1, t2):
    a1, a2 = set(t1[0]), set(t1[1])
    b1, b2 = set(t2[0]), set(t2[1])
    sim =  float(len((a1 & a2) | (b1 & b2))) \
            / len((a1 | a2) | (b1 | b2))
    return sim
```

This is faster because:

- Converting to sets is done only once for each input.
- No useless (but time-consuming) conversions of sets *to* sets.
- No internal function-call overhead for unions and intersections.
- One needless call to `float()` is eliminated (or, in Python 3, the remaining `float()` call could also be eliminated).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it is still very slow... Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user5779223 you open/close your file for every value in `vals`, are you able to change that to open it once?

Comment: "Still" implies that changing to `imap()` made no difference.  Please be very clear, because nobody here is telepathic ;-)  Did changing to `imap()` help, or did it not help?

Comment: It did really help! But it stills take much time.

Comment: @roganjosh Could you tell me how? Cause I just need to write in when the condition is fulfilled. Otherwise the file would be too big.

Comment: Thanks!  Then there's really no reason to suspect that `multiprocessing` isn't working for you.  If `cal_sim()` is itself expensive, that's what you need to think about - but we don't know anything about what it does.

Comment: @user5779223 I just tested and `with open()` 1mil times took 20 secs in append mode to do _nothing_ to an empty file i.e. no writes. I cannot think while permanently having the file open in append mode and writing line by line at a time would be more memory intensive than constantly opening and closing in append mode. Tim will know better to comment.

Comment: user5779223, see my edit for what @roganjosh had in mind - it's a very simple change.  It will save some time, but unless you flush the file frequently too opening the file just once will make it again _appear_ that no progress is being made (the writes will be captured in memory buffers until the OS decides to flush them to disk).

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry that I have misunderstood your coment. And now I change the code.

Comment: @TimPeters I have upload the `cal_sim` code. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Thanks for the edit and you're welcome for the clarification @user5779223. If indeed there are 10 billion calculations (as there has been quite a bit of confusion), then my super-quick calculation puts repeated opening/closing of the file, for every single data point, at ~55 hours of needless overhead _alone_... if you define a billion as 1000mil as in the UK. I got a response from Tim so I'm happy, best of luck user5779223 :)

Comment: Tons of thanks for your help. Although the speed is not so ideal finally... But anyway you help me a lot! Thanks for that. Maybe that's the best Python can do

Comment: Note that doing many billions of things is going to take time regardless of language ;-)  You might also play with the `chunksize` argument to the map-like functions - don't have enough info to guess whether that may help.  In any case, if your original question was answered, you should "accept" this answer so it doesn't stay open:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: BTW, note too there's a whole lot more you could do to speed this, in pretty obvious ways.  And regardless of language.  For example, over the life of the program you convert the same `df[:]` entries to sets over, and over, and over again.  For about 20 billion pairs, there are about 40 billion such conversions, and they're far from "free".  But you _could_ convert the 200000 `df[:]` entries to sets once each, overall saving a massive _factor_ of about 200000 in set-conversion costs.  That's there for the taking, and no language will do it for you by magic ;-)